# Generate a report by Product Name and device

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

We're using GA and GTM (for ecommerce). In the GTM dataLayer, I have product info:

```
  json.items.forEach(function(item) {
        products.push({
            name : item.ITEM_NAME,
            sku : item.ITEM_SKU,
            price : item.ITEM_PRICE,
            quantity : item.ITEM_QUANTITY
        });
    });

    dataLayer.push({
        'event' : 'ordersuccess',
        transactionId : json.MERCHANT_ORDER_ID,
        transactionAffiliation : json.MERCHANT_STORE_NAME,
        transactionTotal : json.ORDER_TOTAL,
        transactionTax : json.ORDER_TAX,
        transactionShipping : json.ORDER_SHIPPING,
        transactionProducts : products
    });
```

I'd like to be able to correlate the first product name (at least) with the device used for conversion.  In GTM, I've set up a dataLayer variable called  "Product Name" with value {{transactionProducts[0].name}}. Am I correct in using an index in this context?

Looking at [this doc](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164990?hl=en&ref_topic=6163649), it seems I also need to add a custom dimension to GA, but for whatever reason I see no ability to add a dimension when I look at Admin/Property/Custom Definitions/Custom Dimensions: [image: snapshot]

(I'm fairly new to this, so feel free to point out the obvious.)

Comment: Does that GA property belongs to you? Or You are given an access to use this property? The only reason you are not able see "New Custom dimension" button is that you are not having proper permission.

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected.  However, I am told I have all the permissions I need.  If you know the specific permission to enable creation of custom dimensions, please let me know.

Comment: I've made some progress in the meantime.  I've created a DataLayer variable which is triggered by a order success event.  The data layer variable uses 'transationProducts.0.name' as its value.  This is the product name.  With that in place, I hope to be able to breakdown product purchase by device